# Why are Virtual Machines operating system/distro specific?

Tags: virtual-machine, grub, operating-systems

Why do virtual machine programs (Virtual Box, VMware, etc.) ask what operating system and, in the case of Linux, distro will be running in a virtual machine?

I would think that the VM program would only care about the instruction set of the OS, and maybe at most the kernel, but userspace (the distro) shouldn't matter. GRUB also exhibits this, as `update-grub2` creates a configuration file specifying the distro (`--class debian` and `--class gnu-linux` as arguments to `menuentry` on Debian). Again, I would think GRUB would only care about the kernel.

Comment: VirtualBox has an option 'Other Linux 32/64bit'.

Comment: @Biswapriyo Yes, I've seen that. But why does it matter? If I were say, running Debian, why/how would choosing 'Debian' on that menu be better than choosing 'Other Linux'?

Answer (score 0):

VM software can emulate a number of different peripherals for certain classes (e.g. HD controllers, NICs, etc.), and the OS/distro choice lets it know which it should choose so that the peripherals can be used with drivers that come with the OS/distro.

Comment: Newer operating systems also support newer CPU instructions.  Allowing you to indicate what you will be installing on the VM is an easy way to enable/disable those features.  I am not saying that **is**, how those features are enabled, just saying that would be an easy way to do it.